# How do I change the color, font type and size of a corrplot?

Tags: r, plot, r-corrplot

I find the red font quite abrasive and the size is always too large. What are the parameters to change the font of the variables?

[image: Ugly variable labels]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `tl.col` to change the color, `tl.cex` to change the size and `tl.srt` to change the rotation degree. Here is an example:

```
corrplot(cor(iris[,-5]), tl.col="black", tl.cex=0.8, tl.srt=70)
```

[image: corrplot]